# Improve performance on SELECT CASE with Partition Plus COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have revised the code based on suggestions but now performance has dwindled. Any suggestions are welcome

```
select *
    from (
    SELECT 
         d.ID, 
           d.HeaderId,
        CASE WHEN h.MyType = 'C' THEN
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  l.Work ORDER BY l.Address1 DESC) 
        ELSE
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  l.Home ORDER BY l.Address1 DESC)
        END 
        AS 'RANK',


        CASE WHEN h.MyType = 'C' THEN
            COUNT(l.Work) OVER (PARTITION BY  l.Work)
        ELSE
            COUNT(l.Home) OVER (PARTITION BY  l.Home)
        END  
        AS 'MAXCOUNT'

    FROM schema1.Details AS d 
        JOIN schema1.BatchHeader AS h 
          ON d.HeaderId = h.ID
        JOIN schema2.Details AS l
          ON d.LeadBatchDetailId = l.Id
        LEFT JOIN LDCs AS ldcElec 
          ON l.LDC_Elec = schema3.Code
        LEFT JOIN LDCs AS ldcGas 
          ON l.ldc_gas = ldcGas.Code
        LEFT JOIN schema2.Accounts ag
          ON (l.Work = ag.Phone AND 'G' = ag.Business AND h.MyType = 'C')
          OR (l.Home = ag.Phone AND 'G' = ag.Business AND h.MyType = 'R')
        LEFT JOIN schema2.Accounts ae 
          ON (l.Work = ae.Phone AND 'E' = ae.Business AND h.MyType = 'C')
          OR (l.Home = ae.Phone AND 'E' = ae.Business AND h.MyType = 'R')
        WHERE d.HeaderId = @Id) 
    ) a     
WHERE [RANK] = [MAXCOUNT] 
ORDER BY LdcGasName, LdcElecName
```

Comment: Just a thought, should it be CASE statement? CASE WHEN h.MyType = 'C' THEN RANK() OVER ... ELSE .. another RANK() END AS 'RANK'

Comment: Case worked but now it's slow

Comment: It's hard to know what part to optimize from just a query.  Have you done an explain plain to see where the most expensive part of the query is?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe SQL does that, supporting AND-type logic embedded within the ranking function that way. You might need to break it into further subqueries. Some extreme psuedo-code:

- Select rank over work for ‘C’
- Full outer join select rank over home for “R”
- Make that a subquery, with the outer query performing the coalesce and all the outer joins

But then you have to deal with the COUNT... OVER..., and that count is not dependant upon h.MyType = C or R, which makes me wonder if that MAXCOUNT will end up equallying the ranking values which are so constrained.

This all assumes I'm reading it right... but it's a complex query, and hard to understand without knowledge of the underlying tables and business logic.